# sequelize findOne does not return even if the same query manually typed in the database returns the data. How to solve this?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, select, sequelize.js, postgresql-9.1

I am using sequelize as orm and postgresql as database. I have try to find the last record which is saved in the database but the returned value is null. In the query function I put a logging which shows me what sql query is executed. I copied it and pasted directly to the psql interface and manually executed that query. It returned a record as expected.
Here is the sequelize functions:

```
 await db.log.findOne({
                where: {
                  card_id: member.card_id,
                  createdAt: {
                    [Op.and]: [
                      {
                        [Op.gte]: db.sequelize.literal(`CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '${currentCourse.start_time.split(":")[0]} hours'`),
                      },
                      {
                        [Op.lt]: db.sequelize.literal(`CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day'`),
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
                logging: console.log
              });
```

Here is the sql query that is executed in the above function:

```
SELECT "id", "card_id", "login_device", "entrance_type", "logout_device", "login", "logout", "amount", "facility_id", "uuid", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "logs" AS "log" WHERE "log"."card_id" = '18af351e-843b-4e46-8734-75119057a417' AND ("log"."createdAt" >= CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '11 hours' AND "log"."createdAt" < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day') ORDER BY "log"."createdAt" DESC LIMIT 1;
```

When I copy/paste the raw sql query the database returns me the record.
Why the sequelize function does not return it right away? it is the same the same logged query. Why does it happen?

Comment: I don't see any result aggisnments in the code. Is it intentional?

Comment: @Anatoly what do you mean with result aggisnment? I passed added the sequelize object also in the db object but I don't know why it didn't work. But now I have changed the code to Sequelize.literal and it worked. Thank for your time!